# spring cloud stream @Input(Sink.INPUT) and @Output(Sink.INPUT) have Bean already exists

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

When I use the spring cloud stream custom channel, I used @Input(Sink.INPUT) and @Output(Sink.INPUT). The following error occurred.

```
2018-04-24 09:05:56.432 ERROR 5916 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'input' defined in com.example.streamrabbitmq.output.SinkSender: bean definition with this name already exists - Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Sink; factoryMethodName=input; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingBeanDefinitionRegistryUtils.registerBindingTargetBeanDefinition(BindingBeanDefinitionRegistryUtils.java:64) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingBeanDefinitionRegistryUtils.registerOutputBindingTargetBeanDefinition(BindingBeanDefinitionRegistryUtils.java:54) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingBeanDefinitionRegistryUtils$1.doWith(BindingBeanDefinitionRegistryUtils.java:88) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:530) ~[spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510) ~[spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingBeanDefinitionRegistryUtils.registerBindingTargetBeanDefinitions(BindingBeanDefinitionRegistryUtils.java:76) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindingBeansRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(BindingBeansRegistrar.java:45) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:359) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at com.example.streamrabbitmq.StreamRabbitmqApplication.main(StreamRabbitmqApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

MySink.java

```
public interface MySink {
    @Input(Sink.INPUT)
    SubscribableChannel input();
}
```

SinkSender.java

```
public interface SinkSender {

    String OUTPUT = "MyOutput";

    @Output(Sink.INPUT)
    MessageChannel output();

}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error simply states that you are trying register a binding under the name of already existing binding. . . and you do. Just look at your binding interfaces:

```
public interface MySink {
    @Input(Sink.INPUT) // will be named "input"
    SubscribableChannel input(); 
}
public interface SinkSender {
    @Output(Sink.INPUT) // will be named "input" as well
    MessageChannel output();
}
```

That said, I wonder what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: In an application I want to create a channel and send and receive messages at the same time.

Comment: We are trying to help, but you're not being clear as to what you are trying to accomplish. . . For example, what does it mean ". . .and send and receive messages at the same time.. . ."? Also, understand that "channel" is an artifact of Spring Messaging and with implementation provided by Spring Integration frameworks. Bindings on the other hand is an artifact of Spring Cloud Stream to setup bridges to the external destinations (e.g., rabbitQueue -> inputChannel). So, once again, what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

To create channel you simply annotate it with `@Bean` and return new channel implementation.

```
@Bean
MessageChannel output() {
   return new DirectChannel();
}
```

The above will create a channel as DirectChannel with name 'output'. All fo the above is outside of Spring Cloud Stream and is pure Spring and Spring Integration.

The annotations you're using are Spring Cloud Stream specific to establish the binding with the external destinations (i.e., Rabbit queue/exchange or Kafka topic).
I'd recommend reading [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_programming_model) which explains it in more details.